# How to access member elements of a std::queue data structure?

Tags: c++, queue, visual-studio-2019, std

Coding in C+, using Visual Studio 2019, I have a structure defined. I am creating a queue of that data structure and have pushed 2 elements into the queue. Now the question is how to access the members of the structure elements inside the queue?? Any guidance is appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>

#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <queue>

typedef struct _myqueuestruct
{
    string name;
    int citypin;
    int employeeId;
}myqueuestruct;


int main()
{
    queue<myqueuestruct> myQ;
    myqueuestruct myQelement;
    
    myQelement.name = "Harry";
    myQelement.citypin = "Ohio";
    myQelement.employeeId = "345";

    // Insert some elements into the queue
    myQ.push(myQelement);

    myQelement.name = "John";
    myQelement.citypin = "Jaipur";
    myQelement.employeeId = "223";

    // Insert some elements into the queue
    myQ.push(evtSvcElement);
    //myQ.size();

    //queue<myqueuestruct>::iterator it = myQ.begin();

    for (int i = 0; i < myQ.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << myQ.front();
        myQ.pop(); //???? How do I access the member values of the elements of the queue?
    }

    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Access the first using `myQ.front()` and last using `myQ.back()`.

Comment: [Each identifier that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex#name-3.2.sentence-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code to get it compiling and working: (Note: I have used `C++17` standard using `g++` to compile this code but it should work for visual studio 2019

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

typedef struct _myqueuestruct
{
    std::string name;
    std::string citypin;
    int employeeId;
}myqueuestruct;


int main()
{
    std::queue<myqueuestruct> myQ;
    myqueuestruct myQelement;
    
    myQelement.name = "Harry";
    myQelement.citypin = "Ohio";
    myQelement.employeeId = 345;

    // Insert some elements into the queue
    myQ.push(myQelement);

    myQelement.name = "John";
    myQelement.citypin = "Jaipur";
    myQelement.employeeId = 223;

    // Insert some elements into the queue
    myQ.push(myQelement);

    while (myQ.size() > 0)
    {
        auto & e = myQ.front();
        std::cout << "Name: " << e.name
            << " CityPin: " << e.citypin
            << " EmployeeId: " << e.employeeId << std::endl;
        myQ.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to point out a few changes I have to make in your above code:

- in your struct definition you used `int` datatype but you assigned `char string` to the same. I have modified the datatype to be `std::string`.
- using `while` loop for iterating through all the elements and using `myQ.size()` every time instead of using for loop.
- `std::cout` - holding the element reference in a local variable inside the loop and printing all member variables.

Improvements you can make to above code:

- There are multiple transient copies of the object being created when you push the object into the queue. I would suggest refer std::queue documentation here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/ and try to enhance above code with
  `emplace_back`
- overload `operator<<` for your class for printing class members, this would help you learn about operator overloading.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with that!

Answer (score 2):

Well, `front` returns a reference to the first element, so like this:

```
std::cout << myQ.front().name; // and similarly for other elements
```

Or, for example, make a referenence yourself:

```
auto& ref = myQ.front();

ref.name = "foo";
ref.citypin = 42;
// etc.
```